# gvfs admin:// in 17.10

Tags: gvfs, administrator

Ubuntu 17.10, (x11), GNOME 3.26.2, Nautilus 3.26.0.

If I start Nautilus and display the address bar, and type this:  admin:///usr  I am asked to enter my password twice.

Why does it ask me twice?

I am able to open files that have the padlock symbol on them – I am asked again to enter the adminstrative password – and I am able to edit the file and save the edits.  However, I am not able to delete the file.

Why am I unable to delete the file?

Answer (score 0):

The first time it asks for the password is to start the gvfsd-admin daemon. The second time it asks is to authenticate to use gvfsd-admin to r/w to the file. Usually, you don't have to authenticate twice after gvfsd-admin is already started. If you want to delete the file, you can open a terminal and type `sudo rm /path/to/file`. If you want to do this in Nautilus you can run `sudo nautilus` and you should have permission to remove any file root has access to.